# Incrementing Variable M$2:M$8 by 7 each row [EXCEL]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to increment the following cell M$2:M$8 by 7 each row (See code below).

Can someone help me with programming the right function? I feel like their must be a smart way to do this. Thanks in advance!

```
=SUM.IF('Energie+WarmteBalans(Jaar)'!M$2:M$8,"<0")
=SUM.IF('Energie+WarmteBalans(Jaar)'!M$9:M$15,"<0")
=SUM.IF('Energie+WarmteBalans(Jaar)'!M$16:M$22,"<0")
etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use INDEX:

```
=SUMIF(INDEX('Energie+WarmteBalans(Jaar)'!$M:$M,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*7+2):INDEX('Energie+WarmteBalans(Jaar)'!$M:$M,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*7+8),"<0")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Why are you using $ZZ1, may I ask?

Comment: @SOAvans it is just a counter.

Comment: Okay thankyou! I needed to increment with 168. Just change 7 to 168?

Comment: =SOM.ALS(INDEX('Energie+WarmteBalans(Jaar)'!$M:$M,(RIJ($ZZ1)-1)*168+2):INDEX('Energie+WarmteBalans(Jaar)'!$M:$M,(RIJ($ZZ1)-1)*168+169),"<0"). = Working :)